# mySQLi Prepared Statement: Fetch() Failing

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

My query keeps failing to fetch. It works just fine in my SQL Console so I'm at a loss. Here's the code.

```
$q_st = "SELECT tryouts.playerFName,tryouts.playerLName,tryouts.mainEmail,
tryouts.secondEmail, players.number FROM tryouts LEFT JOIN players ON
players.userID=tryouts.userID WHERE players.team = ? 
ORDER BY tryouts.playerLName";

$stmt = $GLOBALS['m']->prepare($q_st);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$GLOBALS['c_team']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($pfn,$pln,$em,$em2,$num);

if($stmt->fetch()==false)
{
echo($GLOBALS['m']->error . $GLOBALS['m']->sqlstate ." Haha It doesn't work and YOU     don't know why!!!");
}
else
{
while($stmt->fetch())                  {
static $count3;
echo ($pfn . " " . $pln . " " . $num . "<input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"player\" value=\"" . $em ."\"  id=\"player ". ++$count3 . "\"><br />");
}              
}
```

Result is "00000 Haha It doesn't work and YOU don't know why!!!"

I've tested all the other stmt parameters and they all come through with success. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [mysqli_stmt_fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) method can return `null` and `false` you have to use `===` to check if the returned value is `false` or not (or if it is `null` or not). Otherwise you interpret the return value `null` as an error code, which it isn't.

Additionally your code reads one row from the result with your first `fetch()` call, but you don't handle the returned row in any way. You are dropping the first row of your result set which might not be something you want.

If you want to know how many rows the result set has use [mysqli_stmt_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

Comment: mysqli_stmt_num_rows returns 0. Affected rows returns -1. No error or errno. Any more ideas?

Comment: I was messing with it a bit and for whatever reason it is now working. Go figure. Thanks for the helpful suggestions!